# Как проверить правильная ли ссылка в кнопке telebot?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Суть такая, бот просит ввести меня ссылку на сайт, после чего эта ссылка вставляется в кнопку inline клавиатуры, если ссыка нормальная ( например: https://google.com ) то всё ок, если ссылка некоректная ( например: https://sdfsdf ) то бот крашит. Так вот вопрос, как проверить нормальная ли ссылка или же нет?

Comment: На Английском SO - [How to validate a url in Python? (Malformed or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not)  Но может будет достаточно просто обрабатывать exceptions чтобы не крашило?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить вот такой вайриант

```
import re


regex_patterns = r'((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z]){2,6}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\&\/\?\:@\-_=#])*'
url_string = 'https://sdfsdf.com/123123'
result = re.search(regex_patterns, url_string)
if not result:
    print("URL не найден")
else:
    print(result.group(0))
```